# How do I get digital persona fmd or fid from byte array in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an application in Xamarin forms that uses digital persona which I adapted successfully from this code of Android Java https://github.com/shodgson/uareu/blob/master/app/src/main/java/asia/kanopi/fingerreader/ScanActivity.java

The problem is that this app returns only a byte[] array of a fingerprint, so I consume a web service which takes in a byte array, but I cannot successfully convert byte[] to fmd or fid to compare fingerprints.

I'm trying to use the method `FeatureExtraction.CreateFmdFromRaw` but not successfully

```
public ActionResult validateLogin(ImageSend fimage,DataTable figerUsers) {
ActionResult r = new ActionResult() { 
  Success = false, ResultCode = ResultCode.GeneralError 
  };

        try
        {

           // RawImage x = new RawImage(fimage.IMAGE_WIDTH, fimage.IMAGE_HEIGHT,75,10,fimage.data);
            byte[] x = Convert.FromBase64String(fimage.data);
           // Fmd fmd = new Fmd(x, 1, "1.0"); 
            // byte[] x = fimage.data;
            //duda cantidad de dpi
            //Fid.Fiv fiv = new Fid.Fiv(x);
           // DPCtlUruNet.IdentificationControl.FinishIdentification
            DataResult<Fmd> resultConversion = FeatureExtraction.CreateFmdFromRaw(x, 1,0,fimage.IMAGE_WIDTH,fimage.IMAGE_HEIGHT, 75, Constants.Formats.Fmd.ANSI); ;

            if (resultConversion.ResultCode == Constants.ResultCode.DP_SUCCESS)
            {
                Fmd fmd1 = resultConversion.Data;
                //Fmd fmd1 = fmd;
                Fmd fmd2 = null;
                CompareResult compareResult;

                foreach (DataRow row in figerUsers.Rows)
                {
                    fmd2 = Fmd.DeserializeXml(row["FINGER"].ToString());
                    compareResult = Comparison.Compare(fmd1, 0, fmd2, 0);
                    if (compareResult.Score < (PROBABILITY_ONE / (double)100000))
                    {
                        r.Success = true;
                        r.Message = "Login Correcto";
                        r.ResultCode = ResultCode.Success;
                        return r;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                r.Success = false;
                r.ResultCode = ResultCode.GeneralError;
                 r.Message = $"Error generando objeto de comparacion de huellas\n{x.Length} result: {resultConversion.ResultCode.ToString()}";
                //r.Message = $"Error generando objeto de comparacion de huellas\n{x.Length} result: {fmd.ToString()}";
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            r.Success = false;
            r.ResultCode = ResultCode.GeneralError;
            r.Message = ex.Message+ex.StackTrace;
        }
        return r;
    }

public class ImageSend
{
    public string name;
    public string data;
    public int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 290;
    public int IMAGE_WIDTH;
}
```

it returns DP_INVALID_FID

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't how you got your raw image data, but I was facing that problem three days ago. The approach I used to solve this problem was based on the next steps:

1- I got the raw image data by an application that I created on ReactJS, and with the DigitalPersona Client provided by HID. With the browser side webSdk, I extract the fingerprint raw data, and then make the next conversions: (In this example I collect two fingerprint samples to later make an enrollment FMD)

```
// Decode the raw data from the base format of Base64URL to Base64
const sampleDecode = Base64.fromBase64Url(event.samples[0].Data);
// Parse the JSON fromBase64URL to Utf8, this to get the correct format that DP SDK use to create the FMD
const decodeSample = JSON.parse(Utf8.fromBase64Url(sampleDecode));


if(samples.length ===  0){
  // For the last step I create a Base64 final for send the fingerprint raw data collected.
  samples[0] = Base64.fromBase64Url(decodeSample.Data);
  console.log(1)
}else if(samples.length === 1){
  samples[1] = Base64.fromBase64Url(decodeSample.Data);
  console.log(2);
  setSample(samples);

  console.log('Ultima muestra tomada, ya no se estan tomando muestras.');
  setSampleTry(false);
  reader.off();
}
```

Then I send this samples raw image data to my server on .Net Core

```
const sendData = async() => {

try
{
  await axios.post('https://localhost:7019/api/Biometric', {
    nombre: watch("name"),
    dataFirst: sample[0],
    dataSecond: sample[1],
  }).then(respuesta => {
    console.log(respuesta.data)
    setSample([]);
    setSampleTry(true);
  }).catch((error)=>console.log(error));
}
catch(error)
{
  console.log(error)
}
```

}

And finally, on my server I make the next algorithm logic to make the FMD enrollment
(The next code is in .NET Core, server side)

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post([FromBody] FingerData Huella)
    {
        // Create an array to save all the FMD of the fingerprint collected on the client side, attention here, because I just use to fingerprints samples, but I need a 4 fingerprints samples to create an enrollment FMD, the sdk doesn't create a FMD enrollment if the array doesn't have 4 fingerprints FMD, so I duplicate the samples in the array positions 
        Fmd[] fmds = new Fmd[4];

        try
        {
            _pacientes = new Pacientes();

            byte[] bytesFirstFinger = Convert.FromBase64String(Huella.DataFirst);

            // Here I create a FMD template for each fingerprint sample collected
            DataResult<Fmd> resultadoConversionFirstFinger = FeatureExtraction.CreateFmdFromRaw(bytesFirstFinger, 1, 3407615, 500, 500, 700, Constants.Formats.Fmd.ISO);

            byte[] bytesSecondFinger = Convert.FromBase64String(Huella.DataSecond);

            DataResult<Fmd> resultadoConversionSecondFinger = FeatureExtraction.CreateFmdFromRaw(bytesSecondFinger, 1, 3407615, 500, 500, 700, Constants.Formats.Fmd.ISO);

            // Here I create the fmds array with the duplicate fingerprints samples FMD, to make the FMD enrollment
            fmds[0] = resultadoConversionFirstFinger.Data;
            fmds[1] = resultadoConversionSecondFinger.Data;
            fmds[2] = resultadoConversionFirstFinger.Data;
            fmds[3] = resultadoConversionSecondFinger.Data;

            // Then I create the FMD enrollment
            DataResult<Fmd> resultadoEnrollment = DPUruNet.Enrollment.CreateEnrollmentFmd(Constants.Formats.Fmd.ISO, fmds);

            var algo = resultadoEnrollment.ResultCode;

            var algomas = resultadoEnrollment.Data;

            _pacientes.Nombre = Huella.Nombre;
            // _pacientes.Fmd = resultadoEnrollment.Data;

            return Ok(fmds[0]);
        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

> IMPORTANT: YOU NEED 4 FMD ON THE ARRAY TO CREATE A SUCCESSFUL ENROLLMENT FMD, IF YOU DON'T HAVE 4 FMD IN THE ARRAY, THE ENROLLMENT FMD DATA WILL BE NULL.

This worked for me. Any questions, I will be here.

Good luck programing.